# Kendo UI for jQuery Gird Web API 404

Tags: asp.net-web-api, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am using Kendo UI for jQuery Gird to get some data populated from ASP.NET Web API. The data loads as expected and everything works fine. However, ever since I have enabled server side filtering (which is still an issue to deal with as asked in prior question: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58888706/kendo-ui-jquery-grid-server-side-filtering)) I am often getting 404 error whenever some filter is applied.

Not always the request to filter records fail but this happens occasionally and not always. I am unable to identify the root cause for it.
So far what I am sure about is that there is no network related issue causing this (as have tested on local machine).

The only issue that I am focused here is the occasional 404 in case filters are being passed with the request.

Also following is datasource configurations:

```
            dataSource: {
                transport: {
                    read: {
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "/api/MyController"
                    }
                },
                schema: {
                    model: {
                        fields: {
                           ...
                        }
                    },
                    data: "data",
                    total: "total",
                    aggregates: "aggregate"
                },
                serverPaging: true,
                serverSorting: true,
                serverAggregates: true,
                serverFiltering: true,
                pageSize: 20,
                aggregate: [
                    ...
                ],
            }
```

Comment: Seems like a routing issue. What does your controller look like? How are you passing the filter parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the query parameter got too long in case of passing multiple filters and server rejected the request.

One possible solution was to increase the allowed query parameter length (which I did not use).

Alternatively I switched the request to POST (now having the filters being passed as part of the body) and it resolved my issue.

```
transport: {
    read: {
        type: "POST",
        url: "/api/Data/MyData"
    }
}
```